# Finding t[] array in Sakamoto's algorithm to find the day of week

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, dayofweek

I wanna know how to find how to calculate the values of `t[]` array  in this algorithm?

```
int dow(int y, int m, int d)        
{        

   static int t[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};        

   y -= m < 3;        

   return (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;        

}
```

Comment: You can pick some random dates for which you know the day. Now calculate the day `y -= m < 3;` and `(y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + d) % 7`. Now set t[m-1] to a value in such a way that your answer is correct. Do it for all 12 values of m. To check the correctness of this formula [read this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385190/correctness-of-sakamotos-algorithm-to-find-the-day-of-week)

Comment: [Wikipedia: Determination of the day of the week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Months_table) explains it.

Comment: By the way, this will not work on and earlier than September 1752.

Comment: i have read that post but i am still unable to find out the t[] array,would u plz explain by giving an example @MohitJain

Comment: OK, I would write a small code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [code below](http://ideone.com/D6FX3K) to generate the required array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    int totalDaysInThisYear = -1, m;  /* Parity would make totalDaysInThisYear = 0 */
    for(m = 1; m <= 12; ++m) {
        const int parity = (m < 3);
        printf("%d\n", (totalDaysInThisYear + parity) % 7);
        totalDaysInThisYear+= arr[m - 1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like arr[] is incorrect: too many elements and July and August seem to be in the wrong place.

Comment: @Bathsheba (+1) Thank you pointing, I would correct the array and make the code more readable to OP.