# Formula to add days to a Gregorian date

Tags: date

I was looking at [Tomohiko Sakamoto's weekday calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385190/).  It's a formula to calculate the day-of-week directly given year, month, day.  That made me wonder what other neat date calculation shortcuts exist.

In particular, given an input date as `(in_year, in_month, in_day)` and a number of days `N` to add, what's a formula for returning the output `(out_year, out_month, out_day)`?  Is there a well-known trick like the algorithm above?

One way would be to convert the input to a Julian day (a count of days since 4713 BC), add N to it, and then convert back.  There are formulas for conversion in both directions.  But the combined formula would be quite unwieldy.  Is there a simplified version?

Perhaps there is even a formula to move forward or back by a certain number of *weekdays*.

This question isn't "how do I do date arithmetic in my favourite programming language?"  I know how to call the date library to perform these operations.  It's more curiosity and the hope of starting a collection of cool date algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers in [Algorithm to add or subtract days from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344330/) will be relevant to this.  In particular http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html gives code to convert y,m,d to a count of days and back again.  Those two routines run back to back would be pretty fast.